# incorrect format in string.Format

Tags: string, string.format

I have the following code

```
string x = string.Format(text, args);
```

the text is a string and the args is a in array object[0]

I'm getting the exception
Input string was not in a correct format.

any help ?

Comment: it would maybe be of help if you showed us the input string in question :p also: which language?

Comment: it's like this

__XX          : 2\r\n__XX          : __XX\r\n__XX     : \r\n__XX        : __XX\r\n__XX        : \r\n__XX : 1\r\n__XX     : {}\r\n__XX         : \r\n__XX      : \r\n__XX           : \r\nXX      : 0\r\nXX   :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is c#, you need a number, starting with 0, in the {}.

Comment: even the args is containing 0 element ?

Comment: i don't understand your question, but yes. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I catch your point , thx